# Jetpack Compose open more than one bottom sheet

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I've researched a lot of examples with `bottom sheet`, but didn't find the answer. Do we have any option to open at the same time more than one `bottom sheet`? For example I need to overlay one `bottom sheet` of another(smth like `onFragmentResult`)

Comment: The first question is, should you? From a UX perspective, what message do you want to communicate to the user?

Comment: @Michiel For example I have a view to quick create/edit something and i need to pick for example some date or additional info. I don't wanna use dialogs

Comment: Right, I imagined for some reason you wanted to open 2 sheets at once, which was not the case. I tried it out myself: neither stacking or nesting does not work, which makes me think it's not possible (yet). Would updating the content of the current bottom sheet be acceptable?

Comment: I'm not sure, wanna do that way, so asked) But I'll think about it, if I can't find any solution